# Getting Existing Form Elements with GWT

Tags: html, gwt

I have a HTML file that is linked to a Java class using the Google Web Toolkit.

Within the HTML I have defined several buttons and text fields using standard HTML.

I am trying to get those elements into the GWT class so that I can manipulate them.

Is there a way to use GWT to get those elements and put them into object?

For example, in the com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button class there is a constructor that can be passed an Element. I figured that is where I could pass in the Element after retrieving it via another method.

Comment: __Button(Element e)__ constructor is protected. You have to use the __static Button wrap(Element e)__ function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask for elements within the document...

```
NodeList<Element> buttonElements = Document.get().getElementsByTagName("button");
```

Also you could 'reach' into the JS itself by writing native JS method in your Java-class: [Writing Java methods with JavaScript](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html), and retrieve all forms via W3C DOM [document.forms](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp) collection.